# How do I calculate the maximum northern and southern latitude a LEO satellite can image?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, artificial-satellite, orbit, low-earth-orbit, imaging

How do I calculate the maximum northern and southern latitude a LEO satellite can image? What parameters would I need?

Comment: Angle of view for the camera. Orbit altitudes. Orbit Inclination.  Trigonometry.

Comment: See if https://space.stackexchange.com/q/60109/37597 helps you.

Comment: You'll also need orbital eccentricity, and if the orbit's not circular, you'll need argument of periapsis.

Comment: Here are some equations dealing with the furthest visible point for a given altitude: https://www.celestialprogramming.com/horizondistance.html

Answer (score 3):

For the most simple case:

- Circular inclined orbit
- Camera looking in all directions
- Spherical Earth
- Ignoring the atmosphere

Then you the highest latitude you can image is the sum of the inclination and an angle in a right triangle.

$$\phi = i + \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{r}{r + h}\right)$$

Where $h$ is the altitude of the satellite.

The flat view at the extreme latitude isn't very good.

[image: trig]